# Add existing photos to gallery when importing mixed new and old photos in LightRoom-CC

Tags: lightroom, adobe

I have an SD card which contains a mix new and old photos which I had been using in a digital photoframe. I would like to import those images into a Lightroom CC gallery. When I try and import the photos, it imports the old photos, but not my photos which were already in Lightroom.

I can understand that Lightroom should not import into its 'global' collection duplicates - and I am good with that.

However, is there a way I can still get Lightroom to create an album which is the same as the list of photos I am trying to import - in other words, when it finds an picture I already have - it uses the one from my 'global' collection - so I still have a gallery with all the images I want.